# How do I store 2 pounds of Grated Parmesan cheese

Tags: cheese

How do I store 2 pounds of grated Parmesan cheese? Last time I froze it and it turned to mush when I defrosted it.  I also left in original package and it developed mold.

Comment: did you try searching for "storing parmesan" I did and found this which seems like good advice from a reputable source (EG not some random guy you don't know on a cooking advice discussion board): https://www.cooksillustrated.com/how_tos/5483-storing-parmesan

Comment: @SteveChambers we are not "some random guy on a cooking advice discussion board."  We do strive to accurately answer questions, and the community votes on those answers so that the best responses are recognized.  Sites and links come and go. Perhaps in the future, you can provide a summary, with the link as a source for your information. For this question specifically, I believe the topic has been addressed before.

Comment: It was a self-deprecating attempt at humor, I guess you didn't get it.